# Менять строки таблицы jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть скрипт динамической таблицы

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("body").on("click", ".del", function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
  //new DynamicTable(document.getElementById("dynamic") );
  jQuery("body").on("click", ".add", function() {
    jQuery("#tablici").find("tr:last").parent().append(jQuery("#tablici tr:last").clone());
  });
  jQuery("body").on("click", ".addnull", function() {
    jQuery("#tablicinull").find("tr:last").parent().append(jQuery("#tablicinull tr:last").clone());
  });
});
```

По нему можно добавлять строки в таблицу при нажатии кнопки с классом .add(.addnull) в таблицу "tablici" и таблицу "tablicinull", но строка добавляется только в конец таблицы. Как сделать чтобы строка добавлялась либо после той строки в которой нажата кнопка добавить, либо чтобы строки таблицы можно было менять местами. А лучше и то и то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вам пример функций, которые вы перечислили.

```js
$("table").on('click', ".add", function(){
     var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
     $row.clone().insertAfter($row)
         .find("td").eq(1).text("строка " + $("tr").length);
  })
  .on("click", ".remove", function(){
     $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  })
  .on("click", ".up, .down", function(){
     var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
     
     var up = $(this).hasClass("up")
     
     var $t = up  ?  $row.prev() : $row.next() ;
     if($t.length){
        up ? $t.insertAfter($row) : $t.insertBefore($row);
     }
  });
```

```css
table {
  counter-reset: row-num;
}
table tr {
  counter-increment: row-num;
}
table tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(row-num) ". ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
  <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td>строка 1</td>
       <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove">Удалить</button></td>
       <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs add" >Добавить</button></td>
       <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
            <button class="btn btn-default up" >Вверх</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default down" >Вниз</button>
          </div>
       </td>         
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```